# Aligning Columns - Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I'm currently using `grid-x` from XY grid built from Foundation (Zurb), although when I have a cards layout (as shown below) with `grid-padding-x`, one can see that the cards come centered (which is great), although I would like to put a sorting bar on top of this, aligning this to the card layout underneath proved to be difficult since the card layout adjusts accordingly.

What I would like to have as shown in the jsfiddle, is a fixed width and height of the cards and automatically centered (as fulfilled by using grid-padding-x) although then I would like to give the same margin to the navigation bar on top to be aligned to the cards (margin-left and margin-right)

Is there an easier way of achieving this? or is there a way to align them together?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hjjt2Lp/

[How am I expecting it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rom9d.jpg)

Comment: I can't understand at all what you are trying to achieve... Can you add to the question some images about what do you want and what do you have?

Comment: Hi Gerard; what I'm trying to do (as seen in the jsfiddle) is the green bar at the top to have the same side margin as the cards below.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean? or should I upload an image?

Comment: If there is only one card, the green bar should be of the width of that card?

Comment: I uploaded the image to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to achieve what I believe you are attempting is to put the navigation bar inside a `.grid-x grid-padding-x` as well. This alignment problem is one of the challenges of using a padding-based grid; you have to have everything inside the grid to align properly.

So in this case, you would end up with

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="sort-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hjjt2Lp/2/

Alternatively, if you use margin instead of padding you don't have the same problem. You could shift to using margin grid and no longer need to nest your sort-bar... for that solution just shift your `grid-padding-x` to `grid-margin-x`. See https://jsfiddle.net/uy5euxc8/1/

Comment: Thirs will not align to the cards though, it will literally just add padding.